# Next.js getStaticProps not returning data

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I am creating a blog in Next.js and using Strapi headless CMS as backend.

I was trying to get data from the API I made from Strapi.

For fetching data I made
./client.js

```
export default class StrapiClient{
constructor(){}
/*API_URL = "http://localhost:1337/api/"*/
async fetchData(path){
   const url = `${process.env.API_URL}${path}`
   const res = await fetch(url)
   const posts = await res.json()

  return posts
}}
```

and imported it to ./components/blog.js

```
import StrapiClient from '../client'

const Client = new StrapiClient

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
const posts = await Client.fetchData(`articles`)

return{
  props: {
    posts,
  }
    }
};

  const Blog = ({posts}) => {



  return (
    <div>
   
          {posts.data.map((element) => {
            return(
              <div key={element.id}>
                <h1 className=" text-2xl">{element.attributes.title}</h1>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        
    </div>
  );

};

export default Blog;
```

but I got error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
```

and here is the structure of data I was using

```
 { 
      "data" : [
       "id" /*string*/
    ]

 }
```

Comment: `getStaticProps` can only be used inside page components (components under the `pages` folder). It won't work when called in other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the async function to get data from `Promise`

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
 const posts = await Client.fetchData(`articles`)
 return{
  props: {
    posts,
  }
 }
};
```

> Async functions always return a promise

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: It is still showing the error and I have updated the code

Comment: As @Tauqeer Nasir mentioned, it should be `getStaticProps`

Comment: Its still showing the error

Answer (score 1):

`` const posts = Client.fetchData(`articles`) ``

I think you need to `await` for the fetchData.

Edit:

I just noticed you are using `getStaticPaths` function instead of `getStaticProps`. Can you please change the name and try again?

Comment: its still showing the error and I have updated code

Comment: @ShivamMishra I edited the answer, you have wrong function name.

Comment: I also changed getStaticPaths to getStaticProps but this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

From next.js documentation the [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) method is used to define a list of paths to be statically generated but to fetch data for page you need to use [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props):

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = await Client.fetchData(`articles`);

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}
```

Or fetch data using [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) without use `getStaticPaths`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const posts = await Client.fetchData(`articles`);
  return { props: { posts } }
}
```